# Where should one use tl;dr?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, abbreviations

As I understand, *tl;dr* stands for *too long didn't read*. However I came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching), in which the op said *tl;dr* at the beginning. What does that mean? Exactly what did the op not read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"tl;dr" did originally mean "too long, didn't read". But some use it preemptively as if to say "I know this that I wrote is too long, and most won't read it, here is a short version".

Personally I think the best way to use "tl;dr" is not to use it at all. It is disrespectful and dismissive. But many do not agree with that view.